# Elastic too many buckets exception on nested aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I am running an aggregation

```
    {
      "metrics": [
        {
          "label": "person_1",
          "id": ""
        },
        {
          "label": "person_2",
          "id": ""
        },
        ...
      ]
    }
```

using the following query:

```
{
  "confusionMetrics": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "metrics"
    },
    "aggs": {
      "metricNameFilter": {
        "filter": {
          "term": {
            "metrics.id": ...
          }
        },
        "aggs":...
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And getting an error that the query passed the buckets limit set by ES even after raising the cluster limit from 10,000 to >50,000.

From ES documentation I understood that the query creates buckets for every element in the nested object I am iterating.
Is there a way to iterate the elements in the 'metrics' object without creating buckets for them or to alternatively reduce the amount of buckets generated?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking into this, I resolved the issue by adding a script agg to the query that iterates over the different elements. Its not as elegant but works well and dramatically reduces the amount of buckets generated from the nested iteration.